# Message is cut off on dialog box

Tags: java

The message is cut off on dialog box. Would someone tell me how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

there is my code:

```
 public static void DisplayErrorMsg(String msg){
    //custom title, error icon
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         msg,
         "Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 }
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330076/joptionpane-showmessagedialog-truncates-jtextarea-message

Comment: Yayy! :D Happy coding my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use html tags (e.g. `<p>` ) to accomplish word wrap functionality in `JOPtionPane`.
use

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         "<p style='width:300px;'>"+msg+"</p>",
         "Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`

Comment: my project is desktop app.